# My SQL Report Server (ssrs) Does not allow any users other then domain administrators

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, visual-studio-2015, active-directory, windows-server-2003

I have recently set ssrs on my employers remotely accessed server. The problem I am having is that no matter what permissions i change on the report server itself, whether that is the site settings giving either user or system administrator privileges or the folder settings. Users of the domain cannot access the report server. The only users that can access the report server are the users that are set to system administrators in active directory on the domain itself independent of the report server.

Even if i do not give a user permissions on the report server they can still access the report server if they are an admin. But i have 14 users that need access to the reports, how can i give them permissions without giving them administrator access to the domain, database, and server.

Users experience the following error message "The permissions granted to user 'domain\user' are insufficient for performation this operation. (rsAccessDenied) "

Comment: This really sounds like it is a permissions issue for their Active Directory entry... you will need to give the 14 users access to the server location otherwise I imagine they get a 404 not found error? What error are they experiencing?

Comment: Users experience the following error message "The permissions granted to user 'domain\user' are in sufficient for performation this operation. (rsAccessDenied) "

Comment: OK, that is not related to the Server or Reporting Services then... the issue is with the permissions of the domain user (i.e. Active Directory user). That is why the domain admins can access it, but others can't regardless of their user level for their reporting account.

Comment: do you have any suggestions on how to give a user access to SSRS in active directory without giving them administrator access?

Comment: My official final answer that works 100% for all users is as follows. You must create a user in the database using SSMS. The users name should be "domain\domain users" the domain users is a group that contains all users. as long as that group is added to the logins on ssms in the security folder of the database. then all users can have access to the report server. NOTE: make sure that you give permissions on the report server manager to "domain"\domain users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My official final answer that works 100% for all users is as follows. You must create a user in the database using SSMS. The users name should be domainname\"domain users" the domain users is a group that contains all users. as long as that group is added to the logins on ssms in the security folder of the database. then all users can have access to the report server. NOTE: make sure that you give permissions on the report server manager to "domain"\domain users